# OutOfMemoryError - OOM allocating Bitmap with dimension

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I'm simply trying to **load an image into an `ImageView`.**

However, I'm getting **this error on a Samsung Galaxy A02:**

```
OOM allocating Bitmap with dimensions 960 x 1440
```

**Why is it a sci-fi feature in 2023 to simply load an image into an `ImageView` in Android?**
This image is not particularly large neither. **960 x 1440** is approximately the size of a smartphone's screen these days.

Where should I continue with this? How can I make sure with a quick and easy method that my app won't crash by merely loading a single image into an `ImageView`?

Code is very simple:

```
  myImageView= findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
            try {
                myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_picture);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                //lolz?
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange OutOfMemory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-outofmemory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)